# Plant/ flower identification?

Tags: identification

[image]

Hi. Can anyone identify this plant? Lots of leaves close to the ground then single tall stalk that has small purple buds on it.

Answer (score 3):

That's a hosta. They're great groundcovers for pretty much any shady situation. As to the exact variety, that's much tougher as thousands of varieties have been created over the years. It's possible that your hosta is Albo-marginata, a very old variety.

Comment: Thank you very much!